# depend on debian package not in rosdep database

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-kinetic, bloom-release, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How does one get `rosdep` to install an arbitrary debian package that looks like this...

```
foobar:
  Installed: 2.0.1-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.0.1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.0.1-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

...and is ***unreferenced*** by [`rosdistro`](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro) ?

Is my only recourse to [contribute a `rosdep` rule](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) to a `rosdistro` fork?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306550/depend-on-debian-package-not-in-rosdep-database/) by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 193 on 2018-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got this working for me:

```
cat >/srv/foobar.yaml <<EOF
foobar:
  ubuntu: [foobar]
EOF

cat >/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/00-foobar.list <<EOF
yaml file:///srv/foobar.yaml
EOF
```

---

Originally posted by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) with karma: 193 on 2018-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes; you should contribute a rosdep rule. This typically only takes a few minutes to open a PR to the rosdistro repository and the maintainers generally respond within an hour or a few hours.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-10-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-10-23**:
+1 for contributing a rule in general. If you don't want to do it publicly you can add arbitrary rosdep sources for your private deployments but that makes it harder to share than just listing it publicly.
Contributing guide: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-10-23**:
Also https://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html